# Does work in eclipse but not in an executeable

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

All I want is to get this into a Jar working, no problems in Eclipse, but jar does not play music. I tried several "solutions" from google and stackoverflow.

```
class Soundboard implements ActionListener {

    public Soundboard() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            JButton b = (JButton) ev.getSource();
            // getClass().getSystemResource("images/SomeImage.png")
            String build = "sound/" + b.getText() + ".au";
            try {
                playMusic(new File(build));
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException
                    | LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void playMusic(File file) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
            IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the current information, no one can help you.

Comment: What, exactly, is not working?

Comment: Probably you should use the `ClassLoader` to load the content of the file as an `InputStream`. Also check whether the audio file is in the jar or not.

Comment: @jdv 
I seems that the .jar does not find the Soundfiles located in "sound/*.au"

Comment: @GáborBakos
Where should I add the ClassLoader? Audiofiles are in the jar!

Comment: Those are "resources" as pointed out in the first answer, and how the JVM finds resources at runtime is going to be different when they are in a jar. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171672/java-jar-file-cannot-find-resources

Comment: Or, even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393194/how-to-access-resources-in-jar-file

Comment: @jdv 
getRessource() does not work on audio/images...
ClassLoader was that what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you are creating your jar, the resource files are being put into in a different directory to where they are when you build in Eclipse, so your code is looking in the wrong place. You can see where your files are by examining the jar directory structure with `jar -tvf myFile.jar`

Have a research on where to put resource files in a jar so that your java code can find them.

Hope that helps.

Edit: What do you see when you execute the jar command above? You should see something like

```
     >jar -tvf soap-tcp.jar
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:26 BST 2014 META-INF/
  5118 Thu Aug 21 05:05:24 BST 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 META-INF/logmessages/
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 META-INF/loggerinfo/
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 org/
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 org/glassfish/
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 org/glassfish/webservices/
     0 Thu Aug 21 05:05:22 BST 2014 org/glassfish/webservices/transport/
```

only with your directories and files inside the jar. That will tell you where your packaging process has put your audio files.

Comment: File structur is:
- sound
- images
- (package)

Comment: I'm on Windows, opened it with WinRAR and It looks similar to yours! Problem was ClassLoader...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use the **ClassLoader** to load the content of the file as an InputStream. Also check whether the audio file is in the jar or not. –  @Gábor Bakos 8 mins ago

It's working! ClassLoader was what was missing!

AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(file));

Comment: You should ask him to post it as an answer, then mark it as "accepted answer". An upvote never hurts either :)